# Adding auto hyperlink to images

Tags: image, wordpress, hyperlink

I have created a wordpress blog for images. While publishing all the posts, I didn't use wordpress editor to upload images. Instead, I used FillaZilla to upload the images. Then, in the wordpress editor, I manually wrote only the image tag (below) in all the posts and published it. All posts contain no text, but only images. Like this,

```
<img alt="" title="" src=""></img>
```

Now what I want to ask you is that I want the images in all the posts to get auto hyperlink address same as the image src. I have more than 200 blog posts in my wordpress blog. I don't want to edit all of them one by one. Here's the coding of the wordpress content area,

```
<div class="post-entry">
                                            <p><img src='http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/sun.jpg' title="sun" alt="sun" /></p>

</div>
```

Could anyone please help me on this? how can I add hyperlink to the images? Is there any code which I can put in the post-entry div in my wordpress theme page?

@chandu-vkm explained (in the comments) exactly what I was looking for. Now I have one more question. When I add a a span tag before img , the code @chandu-vkm mentioned doesn't let me add span tag right before img tag. Instead it places the place tag outside the p tag, like in the code below.

```
<div class="post_div">
<span class="entry"></span>
<p>
<img src='http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/sun.jpg' title="Cute Teddy Bear" alt="Cute Teddy Bear" />
</p>
</div>
```

But I want span to be placed right after p, like this.

```
 <div class="post_div">
        <p>
         <span class="entry"></span>
        <img src='http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/sun.jpg' title="Cute Teddy Bear" alt="Cute Teddy Bear" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

Somebody please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with some jquery

```
<div class="post_div">
    <img src='http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/sun.jpg' title="sun" alt="sun" />
</div>
```

like this

```
$('.post_div img').each(function(){
$(this).wrap(function() {
  return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />';
})   
});
```

here the sample http://jsfiddle.net/a4PYd/

Comment: @chandu-ckm Question has been edited. I need your help again :)

Comment: is that text added alone ? is it have any warping tags?

Comment: Sorry @Chandu-vkm I have again edited my question. Now that's what I want to do exactly. Take a look at the edited question again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that all your post content contains only the `<img>` tag, you can add this snippet of code to your **functions.php** file:

```
function hyperlink_all_my_content( $content ) {
    $link = "http://www.somelink.com";
    return "<a href='$link'>$content</a>";
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'hyperlink_all_my_content' );
```

Note that this will link all your content, even on your wordpress pages.

EDIT:

```
function hyperlink_all_my_content( $content ) {

    $matches = array();
    $nummatches = preg_match("/src=['|\"](.*)['|\"]/", $content, $matches);
    return "<a href='" . $matches[1] . "'>$content</a>";
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'hyperlink_all_my_content' );
```

Comment: OP wants thousands of different $link, each equal to the `src` of the various images. The use of `add_filter()` is a very good idea though

Comment: I want to use the image src for hyperlink. Thanks anyways for your help. The above method posted by Chandu works like a charm :)

Comment: i'm giving it a second go! heh.